# Connection to Linux host [ubuntu] is refused from the Local PC

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, remote-access, kubectl, rancher

We have purchased Kamatera cloud for hosting our service. In there, we purchased Kubernetes image and Rancher for creating clusters/nodes/pods, which kind of eases our task. After creating a cluster, we are provisioned with a CLI for each cluster as well. In there, we can use `kubectl` commands as well.

Now, the problem with that `kubectl` command line interface they provide is, it is way too slow. We decided why can't we `ssh` into Rancher through `CLI` tools like `PowerShell, Git Bash or VSCode Terminal`? We created the Public, Private Keys and we could get into the the server locally.

However, when we enter simple `kubectl` commands like `kubectl get pods`, we are presented with the following error:

```
W0916 17:12:03.995526    4990 loader.go:221] Config not found: /root/admin.conf
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

The thing is, we have `/root/admin.conf`. What do I have inside `admin.conf` file? Well, it is the `config`  file we obtained from the K8s cluster when logging in as `admin`. This has been bothering us for a while and the people from Kamatera do not have any clear support for this issue.

Comment: Do the user you are currently using, have permissions regarding reading and editing the `/root/admin.conf` file?

Comment: @AndD, yes sir, I do.

Comment: I'm not sure what `/root/admin.conf` file is (kuberenetes files are usually located in `/etc/kubernetes/`), but your `config` file should be in `~/.kube/config`. Could you please iclude this `/root/admin.conf` file, with critical info obfuscated?

Comment: We had to eventually abandon using Kamatera due to lack of technical support from their side.